# SQL limited by count of unique selected column

Tags: mysql, sql, xenforo

I try to get limited output result by sending SQL request:

But it limited by players count, but i need limit by maps count.

I can't do it and can't find examples in StackOverflow

```
public static function GetWarcraftAccountsWithMapCodeLimited( $startid, $count )
{
    //XenForo DB
    $db = \XF::db();
    //Send request
    $waracc = $db->fetchAll("SELECT acct_username, acct_username_forum, acct_playingmap FROM wc_BNET WHERE acct_playingmap <> '' LIMIT ?, ?",[$startid, $count]);
    // return result
    return $waracc;
}
```

Example data:

```
ID  acct_username   acct_username_forum acct_playingmap 
1   Nickname1       UserName1           TestMap1
2   Nickname2       UserName2           WelcomeMap2
3   Nickname3       UserName3           NewMap3
4   Nickname4       UserName4           TestMap1
5   Nickname5       UserName5           TestMap1
6   Nickname6       UserName6           AndMap4
7   Nickname7       UserName7           NewMap5
8   Nickname8       UserName8           NewMap66
9   Nickname9       UserName9           NewMap777
10  Nickname10      UserName10          NewMap88
11  Nickname11      UserName11          NewMap999
12  Nickname12      UserName12          NewMap10
13  Nickname13      UserName13          NewMap111
```

In my SQL response result limited by row ID count

But i need limited by acct_playingmap

Example needed result limited by 2 maps:

```
   acct_username   acct_username_forum acct_playingmap 
   Nickname1       Username1           TestMap1
   Nickname2       Username2           WelcomeMap2
   Nickname4       Username4           TestMap1
   Nickname5       Username5           TestMap1
```

How to get limited by unique acct_playingmap count ?

*Info:*

Can be 10000 players, playing 1000 maps, for example i need result limited 10 maps with all players playing this maps!

```
(I need to get the result limited to unique number of acct_playingmap values.)
```

*added*

Need first needed unique maps, and then get all player by this value ?
But if maps bigger that 100, i can't do it ? (can be very very big request size)

Answer (score 0):

LIMIT is intended to retrieve the specified number of rows from the select rather than filtering a query.

So, if you want to FILTER by acct_playingmap (In your example it seems you're trying to get records with Map1 or Map2), put it in your WHERE clause

```
... WHERE acct_playingmap like 'Map1' OR acct_playingmap like 'Map2'
```

Or, if you're just trying to show the N first values of acct_playingmap, you could order by acct_playingmap and then limit the result to the first N values:

```
... ORDER BY acct_playingmap DESC LIMIT 5
```

**Edit:**
Try with a nested select, this will get you all info of the first 5 maps:

```
... WHERE acct_playingmap IN 
         (SELECT distinct acct_playingmap FROM wc_BNET LIMIT 5 ORDER BY ID)
```

Comment: Can be 10000 players, playing 100 maps, for example i need result 2 maps with all players playing this maps!

Comment: If you need all players playing X maps, you can't use limit, you should use the where clause (see my first code-example) adding all the extra maps separated by 'OR's

Comment: So... how you pretend to filter (not limit) by a value which you don't know anything about? If you want, for example, filter for 10 maps out of 1000, you want to choose the maps in a random way? how do you set which maps to choose?

Comment: Can be 10000 players, playing 1000 maps for example, i need get result limited 2 maps with all players playing this maps!

Comment: acct_playingmap can be any string value != NULL.

Comment: So.. you want 2 maps or all maps except null ones???`WHERE acct_playingmap IS NOT NULL ORDER BY acct_playingmap`

Comment: LOL! I cant use: "OR  acct_playingmap like 'Map1' OR  acct_playingmap like 'Map2' OR  acct_playingmap like 'TestMap1'  OR  acct_playingmap like 'LOLMap1'  OR  acct_playingmap like 'LOLOMap1'  OR  acct_playingmap like 'WTFMap1'  OR  acct_playingmap like 'WOWMap1'  OR  acct_playingmap like 'BADMap1'  OR  acct_playingmap like 'KICKMAP'  OR  acct_playingmap like 'RussianMapV1'  OR  acct_playingmap like 'MapTestTest'  OR  acct_playingmap like 'Map100500'  OR  acct_playingmap like 'Map11111'" request....

Comment: I just need get the result limited to unique number of acct_playingmap values. (For example first 5 unique maps with all players playing this maps)

Comment: first 5 unique maps = 5 random unique maps?
`WHERE acct_playingmap IN (SELECT distinct acct_playingmap LIMIT 5)`

Comment: First = first, and need get all rows with this maps. If i do it with 'OR', then if maps count bigger that 100, i got very long request size. Or request size not limited ?

Comment: First = first alphabetically or how? try the nested select

Comment: First from beginning by ID,  but there is no difference, can alphabetically. Need get first 'COUNT' unique maps, and then select all players with this maps. If possible need do it in single request without using 'OR'.

Comment: And need using 'START' var. Select unique maps limited 'START', 'COUNT' vars, then select all players playing this maps. Or this is impossible? Or need generate request using 'OR ... = ...' ?

Comment: what does START mean and where do you get it from? Anyways, have you looked at the nested select? I'll update the answer

Comment: I got errors: "This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery' in src/XF/Db/AbstractStatement.php at line 212 " and "XF\Db\InvalidQueryException: MySQL statement prepare error [1064]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY ID)' at line 2 in src/XF/Db/AbstractStatement.php at line 212"

Comment: Possible need: 1 - Select distinct columns (limited 5 for example) 2 - Generate request using 'OR map = map OR map ....' 3 - send request ?? But if the maps are bigger than 100, request size can be very very big!


I do not know why your answer (latest) not working, i got error in MariaDB.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT acct_username, acct_username_forum, acct_playingmap FROM wc_BNET_TEST WHERE acct_playingmap IN 
    (
        SELECT * FROM 
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT acct_playingmap FROM wc_BNET_TEST WHERE acct_playingmap <> '' LIMIT 4 
        ) AS FUCC_MYSQL
    )
```

This works! Thanks [**D Ie**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7126334/d-ie) for help.